# Shoutcast server broken

Tags: shoutcast

I put my free shoutcast server thingy on my website, and sometimes it works, and then sometimes it says stopped, and other people get the problem too. This is the code i used:

```
<script>    
// MixStream Flash Player, http://mixstreamflashplayer.net/     
var flashvars = {};
flashvars.serverHost = "50.22.219.37:33002/;";
flashvars.getStats = "1";
flashvars.autoStart = "1";
flashvars.textColour = "";
flashvars.buttonColour = "";
flashvars.backgroundURL = "http://paraexecutive.x10.mx/fansite/images/background.png";

var params = {};
params.bgcolor= "";
params.wmode="transparent"; 
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mixstreamflashplayer.net/v1.3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the Shoutcast server is turned off or goes offline, not when a DJ goes offline. If you are using a free Shoutcast host then the server make be shutdown when a DJ disconnects after a period of time, maybe the IP and Port may change too. Make sure you keep your IP and Port up to date and make sure you double check that the Shoutcast server is on.